# MFC:set font for dialog childern

Tags: mfc

I am tring to create dynamic cntrl in dialog
like CStatic,CButton like below:

```
ProtocolName_ = new CStatic();
ProtocolName_->Create(protocolNameStr,WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE,rectTitle,parent,clac_id(index,1));


Start_ = new CButton();
Start_->Create(L"Start",WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER|WS_VISIBLE|BS_AUTOCHECKBOX,rectTitle,parent,clac_id(index,3));
```

[image: here you can see how font is other]

but thay font is other from dialog 
why ?
how I can repair the case or set the font?

Answer (score 0):

When do you create your controls? Make sure you create them in `CYourDlg::OnInitDialog()`. Also, pay attention to the `DS_SETFONT` style of your dialog resource.

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632642(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I can't build them in OnInitDialog beacuse I need them dynamicly flow data that i receivce from server